# Getting Tags List for OpenStack Nova Instance

Tags: java, openstack-nova, jclouds

I'm using Java and Jclouds SDK to interact with OpenStack Nova, i tried to get the "Tags list" for nova instances, i used the following code

```
String region = novaApi.getConfiguredRegions().iterator().next();
ServerApi serverApi = novaApi.getServerApi(region);
Server novaInstance = serverApi.get(TEMP_SERVERNAME);
tags = novaInstance.getMetadata();
```

the variable **tags** is a `Map<String, String>` but as i saw over the OpenStack documentation there is an API (`/servers/{server_id}/tags`) that returns **list Tags** here is the [API link](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#list-tags) which is more of what i need than the `Map<String, String>`

the question is, what function in the jclouds SDK that returns that type?
i couldn't find any function in the **Server** class that return that type

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of jclouds doesn't support directly [List Tags](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#list-tags) as per [ServerApi](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/openstack-nova/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/nova/v2_0/features/ServerApi.java#L80) implementation, so you can't use NovaApi to retrieve tags, directly.

Using jclouds portable abstraction for compute, instead, you can list nodes on your OpenStack installation and retrieve the list of tags attached to the nodes in `userMetadata` field, as long as other details with something like:

```
Set<? extends ComputeMetadata> nodes = computeService.listNodes();
```

or

```
NodeMetadata node = computeService.getNodeMetadata(id)
```